# If F is long-tailed then there exists $h(x)$ st $\frac{\bar{F}(x + h(x))}{\bar{F}(x)} \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If F is a CDF for some rv X, and is long tailed ie $\frac{\bar{F}(x+1)}{\bar{F}(x)} \rightarrow 1, x \rightarrow \infty$ then there exists a function $h(x) \geq 0, h(x) \rightarrow \infty$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$ such that  $\frac{\bar{F}(x + h(x))}{\bar{F}(x)} \rightarrow 1, x \rightarrow \infty$.

Any idea how I could solve it? I know the above holds if $h(x)$ is a constant...

Note: $\bar{F}(x) = 1- F(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

From $\overline{F}(x+1)/\overline{F}(x)\to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ it follows that

$\overline{F}(x+n)/\overline{F}(x)\to 1$ as $x \to \infty$ for every $n \in N$

Therefore  $0\le \frac{\overline{F}(x)-\overline{F}(x+n)}{\overline{F}(x)} \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$

So for every $n$ we can choose $x_n$ such that for all $x>x_n$

$0\le \overline{F}(x)-\overline{F}(x+n) \le \frac{1}{n}\overline{F}(x)$

The sequence $x_n$ can be choosen increasing to infinity.

Now define $h(x)=n$ for $x \in [x_n,x_{n+1})$. Since the sequence increasing to infinity so does $h(x)$ and for  $x \in [x_n,x_{n+1})$.

$0\le \overline{F}(x)-\overline{F}(x+h(x))= \overline{F}(x)-\overline{F}(x+n) \le \frac{1}{n}\overline{F}(x)$